# removing multiple subsequent rows with condition in r

Tags: r

I have df as below

```
df
id col1
1   D
1   D
1   D
1   B
1   C
```

I would like to remove when more than 2 subsequent rows "D" happens
result

```
df
id col1
1   D
1   D
1   B
1   C
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df[with(df, col1 != "D" | sequence(rle(col1)$lengths) <= 2),]
#  id col1
#1  1    D
#2  1    D
#4  1    B
#5  1    C
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want this done separately per `id` and that the occurrences need not be consecutive this is a base R one-liner:

```
subset(df, ave(col1, id, col1, FUN = seq_along) <= 2 | col1 != "D")
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form is assumed to be:

```
Lines <- "id col1
1   D
1   D
1   D
1   B
1   C"

df <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: I want only two subsequent "D" only.

Comment: OK. I have added a condition to accept any row whose `col1` is not `D`.